# What is the best approach to join Dynamic Table with Versioned Table

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have two streams that I want to join like LEFT JOIN way. I want just enrich my left side stream from the right one. Let's say my left stream is a `car_traffic` and right stream is a `car_electronics`. The **license_plate_number** is a common field for both streams.

From `car_electronics` I only keep **license_plate_number** and **gps_mac_addr** as @ Mac changes constantly but not every car equipped by GPS module. I'm filtering non NULL values then transforming stream to versioned table view.

The main idea is to have on the right side like a table-reference of cars with **gps_mac_addr** and enrich left side with all known mac@ keeping the values that don't have a match.

The streams moving with different speed.

My questions:

- What is the best approach to join those streams ?
- Which join type should I use ?

We using: **Flink 1.14.6**

Each stream sends around 1,6-2 Billion records / day

Data tables ex:

```
car_traffic
+------------------------+--------------------------+----------------------+
|   license_plate_number |                eventTime |                  ... |
+------------------------+--------------------------+----------------------+
|              AA-123-BB |  2022-11-29          ... |                  ... |
|              AA-456-CC |  2022-11-29          ... |                  ... |
|              EE-935-JJ |  2022-11-29          ... |                  ... |

car_electronics
+----+----------------------+-------------------+--------------------------+
| op | license_plate_number |      gps_mac_addr |                eventTime |
+----+----------------------+-------------------+--------------------------+
| +I |            AA-123-BB |                AA |  2022-11-28          ... |
| -U |            AA-123-BB |                AA |  2022-11-29          ... |
| +U |            AA-123-BB |      FFFF0A0FBBC6 |  2022-11-29          ... |
| +I |            AA-456-CC |      FFFF0A0F00F0 |  2022-11-29          ... |

result I want
+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+
|   license_plate_number |           gps_mac_addr |              eventTime |
+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+
|              AA-123-BB |           FFFF0A0FBBC6 |                    ... |
|              AA-456-CC |           FFFF0A0F00F0 |                    ... |
|              EE-935-JJ |                 (NULL) |                    ... |
```

Answer (score 1):

If `car_electronics` is a database table, maybe you can use the [Flink CDC Project](https://ververica.github.io/flink-cdc-connectors/master/) to catch the changelog as a Flink Source.

You can use the Datastream API or SQL to implement the demand.

For SQL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE car_electronics (
    license_plate_number STRING ,
    gps_mac_addr STRING ,
    eventTime TIMESTAMP(3)
  ) WITH (
    'connector' = 'mysql-cdc',
    ......
  );

SELECT * 
FROM car_traffic c1 
LEFT JOIN car_electronics c2 on c1.license_plate_number = c2.license_plate_number
```

Comment: No it's a stream so there is no MySQL or something else behind.